# Why do second or higher derivatives work for finding concavity and inflection points?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, interval-arithmetic

Say we have the function $f(x)=(x-2)^3+3$, whose graph is
[image]

and we want to find at what regions does $f$ have a positive/negative concavity, and where the inflection points are.

I learned to answer these questions doing:
\begin{align*}
f^{'}(x) &= 3(x-2)^2 \\
f^{''}(x) &= 2\cdot 3(x-2)^1 \\
f^{''}(x) &= 0 \implies x = 2 \\
f(2)&= 3  
\end{align*}
$\therefore$
Concavity is positive within $(2, \infty)$, negative within $(- \infty, 2)$
Inflection point(s): $(2, 3)$

But why does this work? Will I have issues when the function has multiple inflection points or do I just have to be more careful? And what if the degree of a function were very high, say of degree 6? Would I have to keep computing the derivative until I get a derivative of degree 1 or does it only take until the second derivative?

Comment: My understanding is that you use the 2nd derivative test first, if it fails, use the higher derivative test. The 2nd derivative test as the name suggests is independent of the degreee of the polynomial as long as it has a degree > 2. Take a look at chapter 5 of:https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=gzrgCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA61&dq=Higher-order+derivative+test&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJgbX6167lAhXi0eAKHXKWD-0Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=Higher-order%20derivative%20test&f=false

Comment: How do I know the 2nd derivative fails?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a function $f(x)$ is concave on $[a,b]$ if, for every $x,y\in[a,b]$ and for any $\alpha\in[0,1]$, $f((1-\alpha)x+\alpha y)\geq (1-\alpha)f(x)+\alpha f(y)$. This simply means that any point chosen between $x$ and $y$ is at or above the straight line connecting $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$. The first derivative measures the instantaneous slope at a point. The second derivative is the derivative of the first derivative, and it measures concavity and can thus be used to determine points of inflection (which occur when the concavity changes sign). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative) and [this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative) for more info.